# Can you block sessions from connecting to your Snowflake instance from entire countries?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, country

We have a requirement to block all traffic from a list of 35 countries. (e.g. those with state-sponsored terrorism)

I know in Snowflake we can set up Network Policies to block traffic for specific IP addresses or CIDR ranges.

Is there a way in Snowflake to block entire countries?

Comment: Would this be the approach you would want to go?  Someone could avoid that by using a VPN.  White listing may be your best option.

Comment: We went 2 routes. We're using Okta, so white-listing Okta's infrastructure ranges. For a special Admin account, we'll go with local authentication and a network policy for VPN. This fails on a split tunnel, but works in our use case.